# int does not contain a definition for getAwaiter error

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm implementing CRUD in asp.net core. I created a method like below:

```
  public async Task<int> AccessAPIApplicantHistoryDouble(int t)
    {
        var task = APIApplicantHistoryLog(t);
        int result = await task;
        return result;

    }

  private int APIApplicantHistoryLog(int myAPIApplicantId)
    {
        APIApplicantHistoryDto mydto = new APIApplicantHistoryDto();

          _context.Set<ApiApplicantHistory>().Add(new ApiApplicantHistory
            {
                ApiApplicantId = myAPIApplicantId,
                Date = null,
                SentResponseType = 0,
                UnconfirmedReason = 0,
                LastReqStatus = 0,
                Description = "",
                IdDeleted = false   // This field should be totally omited from SQL server
            }) ;
             _context.SaveChangesAsync();


            var myArrayList = new List<int>();

            var result = from x in _context.ApiApplicantHistory where x.ApiApplicantId == myAPIApplicantId
                         select new { x.Id };

            foreach (var i in result)
                myArrayList.Add(i.Id);

            return myArrayList.Max(); 
         }
```

In the line of await there is an error like the following:

[image]

I appreciate if anyone suggest me a solution for solving that error.

Comment: APIApplicantHistoryLog is not an "async" class, so you cannot "await" it. "await" expects a class to return a Task object. APIApplicantHistoryLog returns int. make it async and return Task<int> as well. Also, have "await _context.SaveChangesAsync();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call asynchronous methods like `SaveChangesAsync`, your code should `await` the result:

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Once your code is using `await` *there*, the C# compiler will give you an error, telling you to mark the `APIApplicantHistoryLog` method `async` and change its return type from `int` to `Task<int>`. Once you do that, then the `await` in your other method will work correctly.